# Why does the prior determine the range of the posterior

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Often I have read that in Bayesian analysis that when the data is large enough that the prior may not have much influence on the distribution of the posterior. But I have not found this when fitting some models. In the example below, I can force the samples to be in a specific range by setting these values in the prior i.e. values of `alpha` are in the range `(0.1, 0.5)` whereas in the simulated data it should be $\approx -5$. What am I misunderstanding please?

```
library(rjags)
load.module("glm")

mod <-
"model{ 
    for (i in 1:N){
            y[i] ~ dnorm(p[i], tau)
            p[i] <- alpha + beta*x[i]
    }
    alpha ~ dunif(0.1, 0.5)
    beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)T(0,)
    s ~ dunif(0,10)
    tau = 1 / (s*s)
}"

set.seed(1)
n = 100
x = rnorm(n)
y = rnorm(n, mean=-5 - 5*x, 2)


m <- jags.model(textConnection(mod), 
                         data=list(y=y, x=x, N=n), 
                         n.chains=1)
update(m, n.iter = 500)
s <- coda.samples(m, variable.names=c("alpha", "beta","tau"), 1e3)
summary(s)
#          Mean       SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
# alpha 0.18408 0.081702 2.584e-03      0.0050439
# beta  0.12317 0.117695 3.722e-03      0.0037218
# tau   0.01699 0.002385 7.543e-05      0.0001016

# 2. Quantiles for each variable:
# 
#           2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%
# alpha 0.102040 0.12238 0.15780 0.21760 0.41741
# beta  0.004015 0.03654 0.08820 0.17259 0.43864
# tau   0.012645 0.01528 0.01686 0.01858 0.02174
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bayes theorem is

$$
p(\theta|X) \propto p(X|\theta) \, p(\theta)
$$

where $p(X|\theta)$ is likelihood and $p(\theta)$ is the prior. In your case prior is uniform, i.e.

$$p(\theta) = \begin{cases}
\tfrac{1}{b-a} & \theta \in (a,b) \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

So when some value is outside the support of the prior $(a,b) = (0.1,\, 0.5)$ you *multiply likelihood by zero*, so posterior probability is zero. By defining a prior with fixed support you give your model no chance of finding the parameter beyond this support.

In the [Can I use beta priors in zero inflated poisson model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470045/can-i-use-beta-priors-in-zero-inflated-poisson-model/470081#470081) thread you can find recent question with another example where this goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you Tim  that has clearly explained it. appreciate it.